# Preventing task from running on certain thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, rabbitmq

I have been struggling a bit with some async await stuff. I am using RabbitMQ for sending/receiving messages between some programs.

As a bit of background, the RabbitMQ client uses 3 or so threads that I can see: A connection thread and two heartbeat threads. Whenever a message is received via TCP, the connection thread handles it and calls a callback which I have supplied via an interface. The documentation says that it is best to avoid doing lots of work during this call since its done on the same thread as the connection and things need to continue on. They supply a `QueueingBasicConsumer` which has a blocking 'Dequeue' method which is used to wait for a message to be received.

I wanted my consumers to be able to actually release their thread context during this waiting time so somebody else could do some work, so I decided to use async/await tasks. I wrote an `AwaitableBasicConsumer` class which uses `TaskCompletionSource`s in the following fashion:

**I have an awaitable Dequeue method:**

```
public Task<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //we are enqueueing a TCS. This is a "read"
    rwLock.EnterReadLock();

    try
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs>();

        //if we are cancelled before we finish, this will cause the tcs to become cancelled
        cancellationToken.Register(() =>
        {
            tcs.TrySetCanceled();
        });

        //if there is something in the undelivered queue, the task will be immediately completed
        //otherwise, we queue the task into deliveryTCS
        if (!TryDeliverUndelivered(tcs))
            deliveryTCS.Enqueue(tcs);
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        rwLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

**The callback which the rabbitmq client calls fulfills the tasks:** This is called from the context of the AMQP Connection thread

```
public void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, RabbitMQ.Client.IBasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
{
    //we want nothing added while we remove. We also block until everybody is done.
    rwLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs e = new RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs(consumerTag, deliveryTag, redelivered, exchange, routingKey, properties, body);

        bool sent = false;
        TaskCompletionSource<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs> tcs;
        while (deliveryTCS.TryDequeue(out tcs))
        {
            //once we manage to actually set somebody's result, we are done with handling this
            if (tcs.TrySetResult(e))
            {
                sent = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //if nothing was sent, we queue up what we got so that somebody can get it later.
        /**
         * Without the rwlock, this logic would cause concurrency problems in the case where after the while block completes without sending, somebody enqueues themselves. They would get the
         * next message and the person who enqueues after them would get the message received now. Locking prevents that from happening since nobody can add to the queue while we are
         * doing our thing here.
         */
        if (!sent)
        {
            undelivered.Enqueue(e);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        rwLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

`rwLock` is a `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. The two queues (`deliveryTCS` and `undelivered`) are ConcurrentQueues.

**The problem:**

Every once in a while, the method that awaits the dequeue method throws an exception. This would not normally be an issue since that method is also `async` and so it enters the "Exception" completion state that tasks enter. The problem comes in the situation where the task that calls `DequeueAsync` is resumed after the await on the AMQP Connection thread that the RabbitMQ client creates. Normally I have seen tasks resume onto the main thread or one of the worker threads floating around. However, when it resumes onto the AMQP thread and an exception is thrown, everything stalls. The task *does not* enter its "Exception state" and the AMQP Connection thread is left saying that it is executing the method that had the exception occur.

My main confusion here is why this doesn't work:

```
var task = c.RunAsync(); //<-- This method awaits the DequeueAsync and throws an exception afterwards

ConsumerTaskState state = new ConsumerTaskState()
{
    Connection = connection,
    CancellationToken = cancellationToken
};

//if there is a problem, we execute our faulted method
//PROBLEM: If task fails when its resumed onto the AMQP thread, this method is never called
task.ContinueWith(this.OnFaulted, state, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Here is the `RunAsync` method, set up for the test:

```
public async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var channel = this.Connection.CreateModel())
    {
        ...
        AwaitableBasicConsumer consumer = new AwaitableBasicConsumer(channel);
        var result = consumer.DequeueAsync(this.CancellationToken);

        //wait until we find something to eat
        await result;

        throw new NotImplementeException(); //<-- the test exception. Normally this causes OnFaulted to be called, but sometimes, it stalls
        ...
    } //<-- This is where the debugger says the thread is sitting at when I find it in the stalled state
}
```

Reading what I have written, I see that I may not have explained my problem very well. If clarification is needed, just ask.

My solutions that I have come up with are as follows:

- Remove all Async/Await code and just use straight up threads and block. Performance will be decreased, but at least it won't stall sometimes
- Somehow exempt the AMQP threads from being used for resuming tasks. I assume that they were sleeping or something and then the default `TaskScheduler` decided to use them. If I could find a way to tell the task scheduler that those threads are off limits, that would be great.

**Does anyone have an explanation for why this is happening or any suggestions to solving this?** Right now I am removing the async code just so that the program is reliable, but I really want to understand what is going on here.

Comment: *I wanted my consumers to be able to actually release their thread context during this waiting time*. Are you saying that the waiting threads blocked other threads from executing? That seems . . . odd.

Comment: The RabbitMQ client provides a "QueuingBasicConsumer" which blocks the caller until it receives something. If I were to be using raw threads instead of tasks, that thread would be sleeping and not doing anything. I wanted to avoid this blocking so that the underlying thread could do another task during that time (increase throughput), so I wrote my awaitable consumer which uses tasks instead of actually blocking the calling thread.

Comment: I understood that part. What I don't understand is the problem that you're trying to solve. If the `QueuingBasicConsumer` is competently written, it's a non-busy wait and the blocked thread won't consume CPU cycles while waiting and therefore won't affect any other work that's being done. Just dedicate those threads to RabbitMQ and use other threads for the other jobs.

Comment: I wanted to be able have 1000 listeners while not spawning 1000 listening threads. Their thread blocking method would make me need to spawn just as many threads as I had receivers. I thought it would be nice if I could have my number of receiving channels greater than the number of threads I was running. Instead of spawning 1000 threads, I would spawn 1000 tasks instead which could possibly be running on less than 1000 threads since many of them could be awaiting a message delivery. I am under the (possibly mistaken) impression that tasks are cheaper than threads in terms of system resources.

Comment: The real issue here is that an exception thrown by a task which ended up being resumed onto the AMQP Connection thread caused the task to never be completed in any way (excepted, complete, cancelled, etc) and caused the AMQP Connection thread to hang in general. So, basically it looks like I am unable to mix the RabbitMQ client with the Task Parallel Library.

Comment: I could have a dedicated thread just picking up things from rabbitmq and throwing them into some processor, but I needed a way to either Ack or Nack the message *after* it had been processed and that operation has to happen on the same receiving channel. These channels aren't thread safe either, so I can't just pass them along with the messages unless I used `lock` or something and that could lead to a race if I did things wrong and also gives a slight bottleneck (not much of a bottleneck, however).

Comment: I understand now the problem you're trying to solve. I have no experience orchestrating workflows that way. Sounds like a rather difficult way to do things, trying to persist the state *in code* while waiting for the next message. That's not the typical way I've seen things done, but perhaps somebody else has more experience with that kind of thing.

Comment: `TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult()` usually also executes any code that was `await`ing the `Task`. Could this be causing the problem you're observing?

Comment: Wait...so TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult will execute the awaiting code synchronously on the thread setting the result without switching back to the original context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I first recommend that you read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), which explains in precise terms how `await` will capture a context and use that to resume execution. In short, it will capture the current `SynchronizationContext` (or the current `TaskScheduler` if `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`).

The other important detail is that `async` continuations are scheduled with `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` (as @svick pointed out in a comment). I have a [blog post about this](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) but AFAIK it is not officially documented anywhere. This detail *does* make writing an `async` producer/consumer queue difficult.

The reason `await` isn't "switching back to the original context" is (probably) because the RabbitMQ threads don't have a `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler` - thus, the continuation is executed directly when you call `TrySetResult` because those threads look just like regular thread pool threads.

BTW, reading through your code, I suspect your use of a reader/writer lock and concurrent queues are incorrect. I can't be sure without seeing the whole code, but that's my impression.

I strongly recommend you use an existing `async` queue and build a consumer around that (in other words, let someone else do the hard part :). The `BufferBlock<T>` type in [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) can act as an `async` queue; that would be my first recommendation if you have Dataflow available on your platform. Otherwise, I have an [`AsyncProducerConsumerQueue` type in my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncProducerConsumerQueue&referringTitle=Documentation), or you could [write your own](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/async-producer-consumer-queue-2-more.html) (as I describe on my blog).

Here's an example using `BufferBlock<T>`:

```
private readonly BufferBlock<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs> _queue = new BufferBlock<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs>();

public void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, RabbitMQ.Client.IBasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
{
    RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs e = new RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs(consumerTag, deliveryTag, redelivered, exchange, routingKey, properties, body);
    _queue.Post(e);
}

public Task<RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicDeliverEventArgs> DequeueAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return _queue.ReceiveAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

In this example, I'm keeping your `DequeueAsync` API. However, once you start using TPL Dataflow, consider using it elsewhere as well. When you need a queue like this, it's common to find other parts of your code that would also benefit from a dataflow approach. E.g., instead of having a bunch of methods calling `DequeueAsync`, you could link your `BufferBlock` to an `ActionBlock`.

Comment: I did use the ReaderWriterLockSlim in a way that probably wasn't intended. I used to it say that multiple people could DequeueAsync, but while an event is being handled, nobody should touch either queue except the handler. It wasn't necessary until I added the 'undelivered' queue so I wouldn't miss messages that were received before a call to DequeueAsync. Am I using it wrong? Here is the full AwaitableBasicConsumer code: https://gist.github.com/kcuzner/7242836

Comment: OK, it looks like it would work. But it doesn't get you much over a simple `lock`. I do see another problem: `cancellationToken.Register` can execute its delegate inline, which would cause `SetResult` to fail. Yet another obscure corner condition that I'd rather leave to Stephen Toub. :)

Comment: One more followup question: RabbitMQ creates its threads in the standard fashion with just a `new Thread(new ThreadStart(...`. Are these threads eligible to have tasks run on them or are they going to be left alone when sleeping? If I can know that tasks won't be run on those threads (unless called synchronously, like mine were), then I can probably just use the `BufferBlock<T>` (which I didn't know about before now) and not have to worry about using TPL and RabbitMQ in the same application.

Comment: Tasks will only be scheduled to thread pool threads by default. What you were seeing before was `SetResult` deciding to execute the continuation inline instead of scheduling it. This will not happen with `BufferBlock<T>`.