# Purely computational tasks executing sequentially

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

I have several computationally intensive methods that I am trying to run in parallel using async-await.

I have a list of about 80,000 objects which I feed into a function which returns a task:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //...blah blah blah...

    var runner = new Runner(); //in a nutshell, I manage to get an object that has an async method on it.
    runner.Run().Wait(); //and I wait for it to complete.

    //...blah blah blah...
}
```

I have in my runner object the following methods (more or less...this is a contrived example):

```
public async Task Run()
{
    var items = ... //this is my list
    var tasks = items.Select(i => this.RunItemAsync(i)).ToArray();

    //I don't get here until the tasks are all finished...every single one...

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task RunItemAsync(Item i)
{
    var subItems = i.GetSubItems();

    var tasks = subItems.Select(s => s.RunSubItemAsync(s)).ToArray();

    //I don't get here until the sub item tasks are all finished...

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

    //does computations, doesn't wait on any async i/o, etc
    await this.ProcessAsync(i).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async Task RunSubItemAsync(SubItem s)
{
    //does computations, doesn't wait on any async i/o, etc
    ...
}
```

I have been struggling with async await for the past year or so, sometimes achieving great performance and making some pretty cool things using TPL Dataflow, but every once in a while I run in to something like this where I just can't seem to get the tasks to "activate" their parallelism capability. This particular project is going to be run on a server with ~16 cores, so I would really like to take advantage of that. My development VM only has 2 cores allocated to it, but that should still allow tasks to activate and run in parallel (and it has in the past).

**My Observations**

- I managed to get this run in parallel by inserting a small `await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false)` at the beginning of the `RunItemAsync` method. I understand that this creates some form of "breathing room" which allows another task to use the thread. This is not sufficient, however, since its dirty, unreliable, and requires me to have unacceptable delays.
- Without the aforementioned `Delay` call, the tasks all run on the `Main Thread`. This is obvious to me since `Main` was the function that started it all. I have no problem with this, but I have had [experiences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690849/preventing-task-from-running-on-certain-thread) in the past where running a task on a `new Thread`-created thread caused it to not run with the default task scheduler and every task ended up running sequentially on that thread. Perhaps the `Main Thread` falls in this category?

**My Question**

I understand that running `ToArray` does not execute async code by itself. However, what I *wanted* to happen was that when my `RunItemAsync` method reached its first `await` it would "stop" and allow the next iteration of the calling `ToArray` to run.

I also understand that adding the `await Task.Delay` worked because it caused exactly what I wanted above. There must be some way to do this without resorting to `await Task.Delay`...

How can I start all of these computationally-bound tasks in parallel without inadvertently causing them to run sequentially?

Comment: Do you mean `items.Select(i => this.RunItemAsync(i)).ToArray()` or is that a `Run(Item)` method that you haven't provided?

Comment: Fixed. That's what happens when I rename halfway through....

Comment: It really depends how progress goes forward (one at a time, or in parallel) depending on what RunSubItemAsync does.  Without the details on that it's hard to tell exactly what needs to be changed

Comment: It literally does a bunch of math. It traverses a graph, determines the closest nodes to the object represented by `SubItem s`, determines which of those nodes is best for the task that I am computing, does some data fetches that can't be made async, makes some changes to `s`, and exits. Its completely synchronous. This computation cannot be parallelized, but what I want to do is run many of these computations in parallel on different `SubItem`s/`Item`s. The problem I have is that they never "release" the thread so that someone else can execute and so no other tasks get started until its done.

Comment: When you call it RunSubItemAsync, it suggests it's not synchronous.

Comment: I guess I neglected to mention that as part of the data fetch, it does call `WaitAsync` on a `SemaphoreSlim` deep deep down, but all calls to `WaitAsync` and `Release` on that `SemaphoreSlim` are also done by calls to that same method at the moment. That's why its async: because it might need to wait on a semaphore (and I forgot to mention that. Sorry).

Comment: Since you mentioned TPL DataFlow, why not use it? Feed the item to `ActionBlock` responsible for the computation, with a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` >= 2, and you should be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four major concurrency libraries/techniques available today.

- `async` is best for naturally-asynchronous single operations such as I/O.
- The Task Parallel Library (TPL) is best for parallelizing CPU-bound work.
- TPL Dataflow spans `async` and parallel, providing a mesh/pipeline abstraction for processing data.
- Reactive Extensions (Rx) is conceptually similar to TPL Dataflow but without the parallel capabilities and with a lot of time-related capabilities instead.

In your case, you'd want to use the TPL. A simple `Parallel.ForEach` should suffice quite nicely.

As a final note, synchronous code (including CPU-bound parallel code) should have a synchronous API; and asynchronous code should have an asynchronous API. So you'd want your API to look synchronous, not asynchronous.

So, something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var runner = new Runner();
  runner.Run();
}

public void Run()
{
  var items = ...
  Parallel.ForEach(items, i => this.RunItem(i));
}

private void RunItem(Item i)
{
  var subItems = i.GetSubItems();
  Parallel.ForEach(subItems, s => s.RunSubItem(s));
  this.Process(i);
}

private void RunSubItem(SubItem s)
{
  SemaphoreSlim.Wait(); // instead of WaitAsync
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can understand how you're having trouble getting parallel tasks running with `await` because its purpose is to "...suspend the execution of the method until the awaited task completes".  If you really want to do things in parallel, `await` is probably not want you want.

`await`'s power is that allows you to sequentially declare operations that will execute sequentially but asynchronously from one another while ensuring the results of the operations are marshalled back to a particular thread (when `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not used).  You *could* use await ...`ConfigureAwait(false)` but you're ally defeating the purpose and the generated code is likely slower...

From what you've posted, it appears you want to execute in parallel processing of subitems of an item, and sequentially process items.  e.g. process all the sub items of item one concurrently, and when done, process all the sub items of item two concurrently, etc.  If that's not correct, your code does not really reflect that.

If what you want to do is start several tasks in parallel, I'd avoid using `await` on the individual tasks and just work with individual `Task` objects.

For example:

```
    public Task Run()
    {
        var items = GetItems();
        var tasks = items.Select(RunItemAsync);

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private Task RunItemAsync(Item i)
    {
        var subItems = i.GetSubItems();

        var tasks = subItems.Select(s => Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>s.RunSubItem(s)));

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks).ContinueWith(_ => ProcessAsync(i), TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    }
```

But, it's really hard to tell what you're trying to do with what you've posted.  It seems way over complicated.  If you have a large undefined number of tasks that you want to perform in parallel, spawning of many `Task`s is not the best way to do this.  You have a finite number of CPUS/Cores and if you have more CPU-bound threads than cores you're really just making things slower (see [context switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)).  What you likely want is a *queue* of tasks that are processed in batches of up to *x* tasks (where x is the CPU/core count).  This *could* be done with `Parallel.ForEach`.  but, in either case you're talking something drastically different than what you've designed.

Just because `await` is available, doesn't mean you have to use it for all threading scenarios.